# Why am I able to re-assign a new string to a char pointer in C like so ( ch *string = "hello"; string = "assign";)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, variable-assignment

I would like to know why the following code is legal

```
char *string = "hello";
string = "changed";
string = "changed again";
```

This does not cause any problem with the compiler.

But I was under the impression that char arrays initialized as a pointer (char *string as opposed to char string[]) are read-only and cannot be overwritten?

Comment: You're not overwriting the array, you're reassigning the pointer.

Comment: The variable `string` is just a pointer to `char`, you're just changing what char it's pointing to.

Comment: You're not allowed to do `strcpy(string, "changed");`, that would overwrite the array.

Comment: this is what I assumed, but when I debug this code, I notice that the memory addresses are extremely close. as if I am concatenating the newly assigned string to the old string

Comment: And it has nothing to do with whether you're using a pointer, it's because it points to a string literal rather than a writable string.

Comment: @Jules The compiler happens to put all the string data near each other in memory.

Comment: If you open your executable with a text editor you can actually see the words somewhere in the binary noise. Once the program is loaded in memory, starts and the assignment is executed your pointer points to these bytes.

Comment: `string` point to a location in memory you simply change that location.

Answer (score 7):

Think about this (explanations to follow).
There are big differences between

```
char *string1 = "hello";
char *string2 = "world";
string1 = string2;
```

and

```
char string3[] = "hello";
char string4[] = "world";
strcpy(string3, string4);
```

and

```
char *string5 = "hello";
char *string6 = "world";
strcpy(string5, string6);            /* WRONG */
```

and

```
char string7[] = "hello";
char string8[] = "world";
string7 = string8;                   /* VERY WRONG */
```

Make sure you understand how the 1/2 and 3/4 cases are different but both work.  Make sure you understand why both the 5/6 and 7/8 cases are wrong and won't work (but for different reasons).

---

Explanations:

After

```
char string3[] = "hello";
char string4[] = "world";
```

you have two arrays initialized in memory that look like this:

```
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+
string3: | h | e | l | l | o |\0 |
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+

         +---+---+---+---+---+---+
string4: | w | o | r | l | d |\0 |
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And after calling

```
strcpy(string3, string4);
```

you end up with

```
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+
string3: | w | o | r | l | d |\0 |
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+

         +---+---+---+---+---+---+
string4: | w | o | r | l | d |\0 |
         +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

`strcpy` copied characters from `array4` to `array3`.  (Note, too, that the original `string3` and `string4` happened to have the same length.  It also would have worked if `string4` had been shorter, but if `string4` had been longer, there would have been an array overflow when copying it to `string3`.)

Now to the pointer case.  After

```
char *string1 = "hello";
char *string2 = "world";
```

you have two anonymous arrays, typically in read-only memory, pointed to by two pointer variables that look like this:

```
         +-----------+      +---+---+---+---+---+---+
string1: |     *----------->| h | e | l | l | o |\0 |
         +-----------+      +---+---+---+---+---+---+

         +-----------+      +---+---+---+---+---+---+
string2: |     *----------->| w | o | r | l | d |\0 |
         +-----------+      +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And then after

```
string1 = string2;
```

the pointers are rearranged to look like this:

```
         +-----------+      +---+---+---+---+---+---+
string1: |     *     |      | h | e | l | l | o |\0 |
         +-----|-----+      +---+---+---+---+---+---+
               |
               +--------------+
                              |
                              V
         +-----------+      +---+---+---+---+---+---+
string2: |     *----------->| w | o | r | l | d |\0 |
         +-----------+      +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

> But I was under the impression that char arrays initialized as a pointer (char *string as opposed to char string[]) are read-only and cannot be overwritten?

Right.  And that's what goes wrong in the

```
char *string5 = "hello";
char *string6 = "world";
strcpy(string5, string6);            /* WRONG */
```

case.  `strcpy` tries to write new characters to `string5`, which fails if the pointed-to string has been stored in read-only memory.  For the same reason you can't do something like

```
string5[0] = 'H';                    /* WRONG */
```

Answer (score 6):

The string data could be laid out like this in memory:

```
Addr Contents
---- --------
1000 h e l l o \0
1006 c h a n g e d \0
1014 c h a n g e d   a g a i n \0
```

When you initialize the variable `string`, it contains the address `1000`. The first reassignment changes it to `1006`, the second changes it to `1014`. The string data itself is not being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

> "But I was under the impression that char arrays initialized as a
>   pointer (char *string as opposed to char string[]) are read-only and
>   cannot be overwritten?"

That's "kinda sorta" true, depending on how you look at it.  When the compiler hits an assignment to a literal, it sets aside a bit of memory for the literal and points your `char*` to it.  Depending on compiler and architecture you might not be able to change that memory.  In all cases you should **never** try to change that memory (after all you don't know where it's been).  In that way the actually memory where the string literal (the actual character values) is stored may very well be read-only.

In the case you have shown you aren't changing the memory that contains the characters.  You are changing the address that `string` points to.  Assuming you are defining `string` in a function, the value will be allocated on the stack.  It will be `sizeof(void *)` and that memory can be changed … it is changed when you change what `string` points to.  You are changing the address where "changed" is stored to the address where "changed again" is stored.